# change input type text font using *.ttf file to make arabic captcha numbers

Tags: php, html, fonts

i am looking to change the input type font using *.ttf file, because i want to type arabic numbers in input field to make arabic captcha numbers, i added th code

```
<input type="text" value="إكتب هنا"
  onfocus="(this.value == \'إكتب هنا\') && (this.value = \'\')"
  onblur="(this.value == \'\') && (this.value = \'إكتب هنا\')" 
  name="ct_captcha"
  style="color: #00FFFF; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border:1px solid #FFff00; height:82px; width:180px; background color:#001003; background:#001003; font-family:Arial; font-size:53px; font-weight: bold; padding:1px"
  maxlength="6" />
```

but unfortunately, although i changed the html and input direction to "rtl" it is being english numbers also in force in firefox, opera and chrome, and be in arabic as i want in internet explorer

so, is there anyway to add font file to change the input field's text for example:

```
<input font="fontname.ttf">
```

thank you in advance

Comment: `.fon` files are not fonts, they are ancient bitmap formats that Windows (and nothing else) happens to still support as if they're fonts. You can't use them on the web.

Comment: sorry, i mean *.ttf for example, i hope to make the arabian visitor write captcha in arabic in the arabic section of my website

Comment: don't give "examples", please update your post to be exact and precise. If you have a ttf font, talk about a ttf font, not `.fon` files.

Comment: done, thank you mr. Mike for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: stop doing everything inline, because that's impossible to maintain. Remove those 1998 `on...` active JS attributes and instead do things using modern `input.addEventListener(..., ...)` code in a separate .js file that you import with a `<script src="..."></script>`

The same goes for your styling: put that in a .css file and load it with a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="yourfile.css">` (note that there is no `/` there, nor a `</link>`. The link element is a void element and does not get "closed" in HTML5)

So with that said: load the font using a CSS `@font-face` rule (although I would recommend turning it into a WOFF, rather than using the plain ttf), and then in the CSS for your input element use that font family:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: myfont;
  src: url(thefontyouneed.woff) format("woff");
}

...

input[type=text[ {
  font-family: myfont, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but still english numbers (not arabic)
http://imageshack.com/a/img922/6931/tMASg1.png input arabic words changed their font whose are (إكتب هنا) but when i replace them with the six digits, it is being in english only

Comment: i hope to find it such as this http://imageshack.com/a/img922/8918/bOZ0YO.png it is being in arabic in internet explorer, but other web browsers in english

Comment: obviously (but perhaps not so obvious), also turn on substitution rules in the CSS? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/font-feature-settings

Comment: Thank You, but this will resolve my problem for my pc only, i want to resolve it on all pcs generally, anyway, i will mark the answwe as solved the question if this till make you benefited, thank you very much

Comment: No, it does not. CSS applies to browsers, not "PCs", so use a good `@font-face` rule, and make sure that when you *apply* the font you loaded that way, you also make sure to tell the browser which opentype features to use. *You* have to be explicit about *everything*, or the browser will just do "whatever it wants". Tell it exactly what you want in order for it not to just make random guesses.